# Swift VFL to pin an item a fixed distance from superview's bottom margin

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

so I am doing something super simple, I would like to have an object be a fixed distance from the bottom of its superview's margin. say 20 ios points. I try the following:

```
  addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]-20-|", views: nameLabel)
```

where `addConstraintsWithFormat()` is defined as following (from Brian Voong's facebook app):

```
extension UIView {
func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
for (index, view) in views.enumerate() {
  let key = "v\(index)"
  viewsDictionary[key] = view
  view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
}
```

what this does, though, is place the object right next to the top margin of the superview, as opposed to 20 points next to the *bottom* margin of its superview.

Not really sure how to accomplish what i am aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|` represents the superview, so you need to delete the first one so that your view is not pinned to the top of its superview:

```
"V:[v0]-20-|"
```